# PyQt4 How to draw border around embedded Matplotlib FigureCanvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a pyqt app with an embedded mpl figure like so:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
...
self.LEEM_fig, (self.LEEM_ax, self.IV_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,8), dpi=100)
self.LEEM_canvas = FigureCanvas(self.LEEM_fig)
...
```

This mpl canvas sits horizontally aligned with a stack of buttons which are inside a QGroupBox

The GroupBox has a border drawn around it using setStyleSheet:

```
IVGroup.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { background-color: \
                            rgb(228, 241, 254); border: \
                            3px solid rgb(58, 83, 155); }")
```

Here's a link to a picture of how the UI currently looks
[User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hf34.jpg)

My question is then:
**how to draw a border around a FigureCanvas?**
I naively tried to set a styleSheet to self.LEEM_Canvas which is a FigureCanvas
but that did not work

```
self.LEEM_canvas.setStyleSheet("FigureCanvas { background-color: \
                            rgb(228, 241, 254); border: \
                            3px solid rgb(58, 83, 155); }")
```

The only thing I could think of to try next would be to embed a separate QFrame (generic QWidgets don't support borders according to the Qt stylesheet reference) inside the current tab and place this frame horizontally alligned with the QGroupBox - then embed the mpl FigureCanvas into the QFrame - then draw a border around the QFrame - but that seems like a really roundabout way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to place the FigureCanvas into either a QHboxLayout or QVBoxLayout, then add that layout to a QGroupBox, then call QGroupBox.setStyle() using a QSS style string like """QGroupBox {
                background-color: rgb(48, 47, 47);
                border: 8px solid rgb(108, 122, 137);
                border-radius: 6px
                }"""